# EL evaluation in non-rendered JSF elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

Is EL #{myBean.property} evaluated in example below? If yes, that means all ELs on page are evaluated regardless of value of their 'rendered' (or any other) attribute?

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="false">
     <h:outputText value="#{myBean.property}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is EL #{myBean.property} evaluated in example below?*

No. You could also easily answer it yourself by putting a debug breakpoint on the getter method.

---

> *If yes, that means all ELs on page are evaluated regardless of value of their 'rendered' (or any other) attribute?*

That basically depends on how well designed the component is. The standard JSF components doesn't do that, but if it's for example a custom component which doesn't check `isRendered()` inside `processXxx` methods before continuing processing itself and children, then all the EL of the children may be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks. It is about standard JSF components. Actually, I have a more complicated example. In a nutshell, I'm trying to defer the creation of myBean until one of the components that references myBean through EL is rendered.

Comment: I tried simple example like one above. EL is evaluated though. Comments? Btw. I'm using JSF 1.2 implementation which comes with JBoss AS 5.1, if that can make any difference.

Comment: "like"? So it's not exactly the given example? Are you using `rendered="#{bean.someCondition}"`? Then apparently that condition evaluated `true` at some point. Again, just run the debugger.

Comment: I tried inserting example identical to one above, with simple request bean myBean in several parts of my application. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. After experimenting I found that presence of Facelets tag `<ui:debug rendered="true"/>` makes these non-rendered ELs to evaluate.